# Node js can I get the exit code from the windows command line app written in C++?

Tags: c++, node.js, windows, command-line

I have a small utility - a Windows executable written in C++ that returns either 0 or 1 as its exit code.
I can run this C++ executable from Node js and pass command line arguments there.
Is there any way I can read the exit code of the command line app in Node js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you get it as a parameter for the close event.
To cite the example code from the documentation:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```